# AMDGPU drivers from AMD directly

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu, 22.10

I have an AMD Radeon RX 6700 graphics card in my system, right now I just have the X.org driver that was originally from my 5700G APU. I am looking to actually install the AMDGPU drivers on my system and on AMD's website, they have drivers for Ubuntu and Linux. The only issue that I want to find out first is the drivers are shown to be certified to work with only the LTS releases and I have 22.10 currently on my system. Does anyone know if the drivers would work with the non-LTS releases? According to AMD, I should change back to 22.04, since they know it will work with that, but they are unaware if the driver will work with the non-LTS releases.

Comment: You don't need to install any drivers. AMD provides open source drivers that are included in Ubuntu. You can see that `amdgpu` is in use by running `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

Comment: So, even if the drivers are being done by X.org right now, it doesn't matter? Are the drivers that AMD has on their website ones that have more features than just display?

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU_PRO